# How to get RGB color-format frames using MediaCodec encoder

Tags: android, opencv, colors, video-processing, android-mediacodec

I've created an encoder using the Android's MediaCodec API using the following code :

```
MediaFormat mMediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", width, height);
            mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bitrate);
            mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 15);
            mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,     MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
            mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 10);
            Log.i(TAG, "Starting encoder");
            encoder = MediaCodec.createByCodecName(Utils.selectCodec("video/avc").getName());
            encoder.configure(mMediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
            Surface surface = encoder.createInputSurface();
            encoder.start();
```

I'm using `createInputSurface()` to pass the input to the encoder. The problem is I want RGB color-format frames in the subsequent calls to `dequeueOutputBuffer()` but since I've set the color format to `MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface` so I think I'm not getting RGB frames. I need to pass these frames to OpenCv for image processing.
Is there any way to get RGB frames from `dequeueOutputBuffer()` ?

**Note** : I cannot set RGB as the color format during the configuring of the encoder because it's not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the encoder is AVC-encoded frames.  It's not RGB or YUV, it's AVC.

The color format specifies the format of the frames you're feeding *into* the encoder, not what comes *out*, so it has no effect on what you get from `dequeueOutputBuffer()`.

If you need to manipulate the raw frames, you should do so before passing them into the encoder.

Comment: On a separate note I want to ask can I create a Bitmap out of these AVC encoded frames or I need to first pass them to the decoder ?

Comment: You need to feed the encoded stream into the decoder.  Frames may be encoded as deltas from previous frames, so you can't treat them individually (see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types).  For an example of extracting frames from an AVC stream, see http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#ExtractMpegFramesTest .

Comment: Can you somehow instruct the encoder or decoder to encode/decode to RGB frames? You mentioned the frames are AVC but my end goal is to get an RGB decoded frame.